# The server is unable to process the 4.0 version and the http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee namespace in the /META-INF/web-fragment.xml

Tags: open-liberty

I'm trying to convert a service that runs on websphere 8.5 to open liberty.  I'm getting the error below.  How can I find more details on this?  I'm assuming something in my web.xml is not supported in my list of features.  Is that correct?

How can I find the web-fragment.xml file the error is referring to?  There is no such file in my project, so I'm not clear what is on the line that is causing the issue.

```
CWWKC2262E: The server is unable to process the 4.0 version and the http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee namespace in the /META-INF/web-fragment.xml
 deployment descriptor on line 23


<featureManager>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the 4.0 spec you need `servlet-4.0` feature not `3.1`, and also set  `jdbc-4.2`, and `jaxrs-2.1`.
Your `server.xml` just has 3.1 features not 4.0 so update them accordingly.
You can see the features versions here https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/jakartaee-8.0.html